# How to use the "__ProviderArchitecture" flag of IWbemContext in c?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wmi

I've been trying to follow the following [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query the 64 bit registry provider from a 32 bit application.

Sadly, the examples are all written in VB, and I'm stuck with something.

For C++ developers, the article mentions that...

> C++ applications can use the IWbemContext interface with IWbemServices::ExecMethod to communicate the use of a nondefault provider to WMI.

...although, when you look at the sample VB code, the context object is also used in the `ConnectServer` method:

```
Set objCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
objCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", 32
Set objLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objServices = objLocator.ConnectServer("","root\default","","",,,,objCtx)
Set objStdRegProv = objServices.Get("StdRegProv")
```

I've tried reproducing this in VC++:

```
HRESULT res;
CComPtr<IWbemContext> ctx;
if (!create_registry_redirection_context_(hive, ctx)) {
    return false;
}

res = locator_->ConnectServer(CComBSTR(namespace_.c_str()),     // Namespace to use
                              0,                                // Current security context (username)
                              0,                                // Current security context (password)
                              0,                                // Use current locale
                              WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT,   // Return if connexion is unsuccessful after 2 minutes
                              0,                                // Name of the domain  of the user to authenticate
                              ctx,                              // Optional context
                              &service_);                       // Fill this pointer
```

The `create_registry_redirection_context_` method uses `CoCreateInstance` to instantiate my context, and I use the following lines to set the architecture:

```
CComVariant value_arch(64, VT_I4);
ctx->SetValue(L"__ProviderArchitecture", 0, &value_arch);
```

Now the problem is, the `ConnectServer` method returns an error (0x80041008 - WMI Invalid Parameter). If I comment out the `ctx->SetValue(L"__ProviderArchitecture", 0, &value_arch);` line, everything works properly, but of course, I end up querying the 32 bit registry provider.

I've also tried not setting any context during the `ConnectServer` call, but only during the `ExecMethod` call (as specified in the MSDN article), but although I don't get any error, I'm still querying the 32 bit provider, and not seeing my 64bit registry keys.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's a little bit late, but for archive (and because MS is unable to provide such a sample):

```
  HRESULT hres;
  IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
  hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc); 
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
    m_nExitCode = TCP1;
    return FALSE;
  }

  IWbemContext *pContext = NULL;
  hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemContext, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemContext, (LPVOID *) &pContext); 
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
    m_nExitCode = TCP1_2;
    return FALSE;
  }

  VARIANT vArchitecture;
  VariantInit(&vArchitecture);
  V_VT(&vArchitecture) = VT_I4;
  V_INT(&vArchitecture) = 64;
  hres = pContext->SetValue(_bstr_t(L"__ProviderArchitecture"), 0, &vArchitecture);
  VariantClear(&vArchitecture);

  //VARIANT vRequiredArchicture;
  //VariantInit(&vRequiredArchicture);
  //V_VT(&vRequiredArchicture) = VT_BOOL;
  //V_BOOL(&vRequiredArchicture) = VARIANT_TRUE;
  //hres = pContext->SetValue(_bstr_t(L"__RequiredArchitecture"), 0, &vRequiredArchicture);
  //VariantClear(&vRequiredArchicture);

  IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

  hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
     _bstr_t(L"root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement10"), // Object path of WMI namespace
     NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
     NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
     0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
     NULL,                    // Security flags.
     0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
     pContext,               // Context object 
     &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
     );
```

The block with RequiredArchitecture is untested and seems to be unnecessary.
PS: Error-handling needs to be improved!

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393067(v=vs.85).aspx
and tried setting  "__RequiredArchitecture" = TRUE as well?

Also have to tried to get it to work in the way that the same code shows ( ie 64 bit to 32 bit) first?